# Is "Always err on the side of giving [...] information" obvious?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

I found a comment on one of the videos in the Khan Academy site, which is something along the lines of...

> Always err on the side of giving too much information.

(The subject was maths, and the poster's English seemed idiomatic enough.)

I'd parsed the above as:

> While writing an answer to a maths problem, you're stuck between the choice of giving or not giving some information. Your answer could be either "lacking" or "have unnecessary/more than required info" if you choose to go with any one option. Either way you could make a mistake. But it's always safer to go with the latter (option). At least you've included all the possible information you can. So it all boils down to this — if you've to err, err on the side of giving too much information.

To my non-native ear, it doesn't sound immediately obvious. It might even be ungrammatical, but that doesn't seem very likely.

**Question**:

> Is the sentence
>
> - idiomatic
> - obvious enough to native speakers
> - grammatical
>
> **?**

Comment: There's nothing at all ungrammatical in the quote, and although I would have to see the comment in context, your surmise sounds reasonable. It's a _very_ common expression in English, as is obvious from **[this search.](https://www.google.com/search?q="Always+err+on+the+side+of+giving+too+much+information.")** This means that it's obvious and idiomatic (not "idiomatical", though.)

Comment: By the way, Pinky, there's a mistake in this sentence: _"Either ways you'd make a mistake."_ Can you spot it? 50 quatloo reward if you catch it without help! :)

Comment: @P.E.Dant _Either ways you could make a mistake._ I was writing on my phone really fast. I also made many other typos and mistakes because of that: "idiomatical" instead of "idiomatic" the second time (but got it right the first time), "biols" instead of "boils", and that grammatical error.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Anyways, I object to being called "Pinky'. I know you said that jokingly. But, I've a proper name.

Comment: Please accept my apology. My own daughter's nickname is _Pinky,_ and I thought it quite charmingly coincidental that you went by the same sobriquet. No disrespect was intended, and typographical errors are inconsequential. (It would be most amusing if you should know what a _quatloo_ is!)

Comment: @P.E.Dant It's perfectly alright. Actually, my mother made this username, but I absolutely hate pink. I love colours because they're colourful, not because I'm expected to. Pink is too "girly" for me. The name's sweet however.

Comment: Well, you see, my favorite color is pink! If it's instructive, you might be interested to know that my own daughter hated the nickname as well, until the last couple of years. She is at university now, and often signs her letters to me: "love, Pinky".

Comment: @P.E.Dant Wow. She's at university and still uses such a childish nickname. Good to know I'm not the only one (who hates a name like that).

Comment: I like to think that she is sufficiently confident to use any nickname she likes! I hope the same is true of you. It isn't the name you go by, but what you _do_, that matters.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Of course. And it's very cute too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61432/discussion-between-soha-farhin-pine-and-p-e-dant).

Comment: They're not saying that your answer can either be lacking or containing too much information (they're not excluding these possibilities, mind) – what they're suggesting is, I assume, that if you find yourself in a situation in which you don't know what information to include, you're *allowed to* err, in that regard, on the side of giving too much of it (because, obviously, you don't want to omit an important piece of information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> Always err on the side of giving too much information.

is grammatical and understandable.

The meaning behind your sentence is that, while math tends to be a fairly exact science, in a test environment students are usually encouraged to "show all their work" with the possibility of receiving *partial credit* even if they cannot solve the problem.